# Map Reduce - How to plan the data files

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, emr, hue

I would like to use AWS EMR to query large log files that I will write to S3. I can design the files any way I like. The data is created in a rate of 10K entries/minute.

The logs consist of dozens of data points and I'd like to collect data for very long period of time (years) to compare trends etc.

What are the best practices for creating such files that will be stored on S3 and queried by AWS EMR cluster?

Whats the optimal file sizes ?Should I create separate files for example on hourly basis?

What is the best way to name the files?

Should I place them in daily/hourly buckets or all in the same bucket?

Whats the best way to handle things like adding some data after a while or change in data structure that I use?

Should I compress things for example by leaving out domain names out of urls or keep as much data as possible?

Is there any concept like partitioning (the data is based on 100s of websites so I can use site ids for example). I must be able to query all the data together, or  by partitions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my opinion you should use a hourly basis bucket to store data in s3 and then use a pipeline to schedule your mr job to clean the data.
once u have clean the data you can keep it to a location in s3 and then you can run a data pipeline on hourly basis on the lag of 1hour with respect to your MR pipeline to put this process data into redshift.

Hence at 3am on a day you will have 3 hour of processed data in s3 and 2 hour processed into redshift dB.

To do this you can have 1 machine dedicated for running pipelines and on that machine you can define you shell script/perl/python or so script to load data to your dB.
You can use AWS bucketing formatter for year,month,date,hour and so on. for e.g.

> {format(minusHours(@scheduledStartTime,2),'YYYY')}/mm=#{format(minusHours(@scheduledStartTime,2),'MM')}/dd=#{format(minusHours(@scheduledStartTime,2),'dd')}/hh=#{format(minusHours(@scheduledStartTime,2),'HH')}/*